# Retrieving values from object with array

Tags: jquery

I am working on method code in which I have to iterate through an json object with dynamic array. my code is like this:

```
var tableHeaders = ["id", "name", "status"];    
var item = {
    id: 1,
    name: "test name",
    status: true,
    email: "test@gmail.com"
}    
console.log(item.id);    // works well --> 1    
console.log(tableHeaders[0]); // works well --> id    
console.log(item.tableHeaders[0]);  // not works
```

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kslagdive/rjFHV/
Please suggest me, how can I get value of item with Array element? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your property name is dynamic, you have to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) instead of [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Dot_notation):

```
console.log(item[tableHeaders[0]]);  // Works.
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be...

```
item[ tableHeaders[0] ];
```

... that is, using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) to access a property by its name. Note that you use any complex expression here, for example:

```
item[ 'e' + 'mail' ]; // the same as item.email
```

Comment: Yes okay. Got it using bracket notation instead of dot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Need to use `[]` notation instead of `.` notation when you use dynamic keys

```
console.log(item[tableHeaders[0]]);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rszc9/)

Comment: Got it using bracket notation instead of dot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Tabheaders is not a value of item. Try

```
var tableHeaders = ["id", "name", "status"];    
var item = {
    id: 1,
    name: "test name",
    status: true,
    email: "test@gmail.com",
    tableHeaders: tableHeaders // define "tableHeaders" as value of "item"
}
```

Thanks @xec for your comment.

Well the answer is already here but anyway:

```
var key = tableHeaders[0];  // the key for the value you want to extract from items.
var value = item[key];      // get the value from item based on the key defined 
                            // in table headers using the [Bracket notation][1] 
                            // (@Frédéric Hamidi).
```

Comment: I believe he wants `1` returned (the value of the `id` property)